# Django can't find location to load templates/css from

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-settings

I included the path to my templates folder in the settings.py file by setting:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

and likewise for `STATIC_FILES_DIR`, but I keep getting the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error. When I look at the postmortem of the error, I see:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\home.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\home.html (File does not exist)
```

Why would the template.loader be looking for the template files in that directory instead of the one specified in my `settings.py` file? Also, when I copy over my `home.html` page into the first directory mentioned in the error message, the page loads the content without error, so how can I get the loader to move from the location that it's searching to the directory where the files are actually located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid setting name is [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_DIRS) and it is a tuple of strings, not the simple string:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )
```

Comment: Note for future visitors: This setting is deprecated in favor of [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings) as of Django 1.8.

Comment: Is there another possible explanation? The error persists even when I make this change.

Comment: @Selcuk yes, you ar right. But the settings stilll the plural `DIRS` and the tuple type :-)

Comment: According to error django uses only the app template dirs.  If you use django 1.8 then read the @Selcuk's comment about deprecation of this setting and change it to `TEMPLATES`.

Comment: this is in Django 1.7

Comment: Are you sure that you changed the setting name?  If you set the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to non-empy list then at least one line should be added to the error stack trace before these two app directories.